# How to avoid the re-loading of remote images in a continuous listview with android-volley?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-volley

I'm experimenting with the volley library. I got it to download a set of items, put them into the listview and load the remote images each item has OK. Encouraged by that, I tried to implement a continuous listview, so I could waive the pagination controls.

The website I'm requesting the data from serves it in pages with 10 items each, so I added a check on my adapter.getView so that if position was 2 prior to the end of the page (position 8 for page 1, 18 for page 2, etc), it should load a new page and append the new items to the end of the list. It works, but the behaviour isn't what I expected.

First page loads ok, images take some seconds to load, but it's ok. Then, when I scroll down, when it loads the new pages, all **the images that already were displayed dissapear**, though they show up again along with the new ones. This is, it loads ok first 10 pictures, then it "hiccups" making them dissapear, and they reappear along with the next 10 pictures. The data, however, loads ok and doesn't dissapear or anything similar.

This is my ArrayAdapter

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements Listener<JSONObject>, ErrorListener{

private static final String TAG = VolleyTestApp.LOGTAG;

private final Context mCtx;
private final ArrayList<Item> items;

//private int elegido = -1;
ItemsViewHolder viewHolder;

/**********************************/
private int pageSize = 0;
private int currentPage = 0;
private boolean mLoading = false;
private RequestQueue rq;
private ItemsListRequestParameter params;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, resource, 
            objects);
    mCtx = context;
    items = (ArrayList<Item>) objects;
    rq = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(mCtx);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    LayoutInflater vi = ((Activity) mCtx).getLayoutInflater();

    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_list_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ItemsViewHolder(v);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter viewholder creado " );

    v.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder = (ItemsViewHolder) v.getTag();


    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter posición: " + position);

    if(viewHolder != null){
        if (items.size() > 0){
            Log.d(TAG, "Adapter tamaño lista: " + getCount());
            Item t = items.get(position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Adapter devolviendo item: " + items.get(position).getItemName());
            String foto = t.getItemPicUrl();
            if (foto == null || foto.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                viewHolder.itemPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_default_item_thumbnail);
            }else{
                Log.d(TAG, "Adapter devolviendo item foto: " + foto);
                int cacheSize = getCacheSize();
                Log.d(TAG, "Adapter cacheSize: " + cacheSize);
                BitmapLruImageCache cache = new BitmapLruImageCache(cacheSize);
                ImageLoader imgLoader = 
                        new ImageLoader(SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(mCtx),
                                cache);

                viewHolder.itemPic.setImageUrl(foto, imgLoader);
            }
            viewHolder.itemName.setText(t.getItemName());
            viewHolder.itemData1.setText(t.getData1());

        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Adapter viewHolder null: " );
    }
    /**************************************************/
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.getView posición: " + position + "; pageSize: " + pageSize + "; currentPage: " + currentPage);
    if (position +2 == (this.pageSize * (this.currentPage +1)  )&& !mLoading){
        Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.getView pidiendo nuevos datos");
        if(this.params == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "Adapter.getView params null " );
        }else{
            Log.w(TAG, "Adapter.getView nueva carga" );
            this.params.nextPage();
            this.loadData(this.params, pageSize);
        }
    }

    return v;
}


public int getCacheSize() {
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mCtx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    final int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    final int screenBytes = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4; // 4 bytes per pixel

    return screenBytes * 3;
}




@Override
public void add(Item object) {
    items.add(object);
    Log.d(TAG, "Item añadida a adapter: " + object.getItemName());
}
@Override
public void clear() {
    //super.clear();
    items.clear();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}



static class ItemsViewHolder{
    TextView        itemName;
    TextView        itemData1;
    NetworkImageView itemPic;

    LinearLayout container;

    public ItemsViewHolder(View v){
        this.itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lti_nombre_item);
        this.itemData1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lti_datos_item1);
        this.itemPic = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tli_r_img);
        this.container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lti_container);
    }

}



public void loadData(ItemsListRequestParameter params, int pageSize){
    mLoading = true;
    ItemListRequest jr = new ItemListRequest(params, this, this);
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.params = params;
    this.rq.add(jr);    
}



@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.onErrorResponse request con error");
    mLoading = false;
    // TODO meter elemento con mensaje error
    Log.i(TAG, "Adapter.onErrorResponse request respondida " + error.getMessage());

}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.onResponse request respondida " + response.toString());
    mLoading = false;
    Response tr = ResponseParser.parseUltimasItemsJSONresponse(response);
    if (tr.getResponseCode().equalsIgnoreCase("000")){
        DaoList tdl = (DaoList) tr.getResponseInfo(); 
        this.currentPage = tdl.getCurrentPage();
        Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.onResponse  currentPage: " + currentPage);
        Iterator<Dao> it = tdl.iterator();
        //tta.clear();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Item t = (Item) it.next();
            this.add(t);
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

}
```

My ItemListRequest sub-subclasses a modified version of the volley Request

BaseRequest

```
public class BaseRequest extends Request<JSONObject>{


private Listener<JSONObject> mListener;

public BaseRequest(int method, 
        String url,
        Listener<JSONObject> successListener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(method,url,errorListener);
    this.mListener = successListener;

}

/**
 * transform NetworkResponse into Response<JSONObject>
 */
@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString =
            new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}


/**
 * Here we send the response to the successListener
 */
@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    this.mListener.onResponse(response);
}

}
```

PostRequest

```
public class PostRequest extends BaseRequest {

private Map<String, String> mParams;
private static int method = Method.POST;
public PostRequest(ItemsListRequestParameter params,
        String url, Listener<JSONObject> successListener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super(method, url, successListener, errorListener);
    this.mParams = params.getMappedParams();
}

/**
 * Override getParams so that it returns our POST params
 */
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError { 
    return mParams;
}

}
```

And the ItemListRequest, the actual Request I do use in my Adapter

```
public class ItemListRequest extends PostRequest{

public ItemListRequest(TapasListRequestParameter params,
        Listener<JSONObject> successListener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {

    super( params, RequestData.SEARCH_TAPAS_LIST_URL,successListener, errorListener);

    this.setShouldCache(Boolean.TRUE);


}

}
```

I really don't get the reason behind the images re-loading. Any help about how preventing it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I had some outside help and got to figure it out: I was re-creating the image cache on every getView execution. The trick is to move out the creation of the cache object. **Best idea would be a Singleton**, but just for the sake of this experiment, I'll leave it on the Adapter class:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements Listener<JSONObject>, ErrorListener{

private static final String TAG = VolleyTestApp.LOGTAG;

private final Context mCtx;
private final ArrayList<Item> items;

//private int elegido = -1;
ItemsViewHolder viewHolder;

/**********************************/
private int pageSize = 0;
private int currentPage = 0;
private boolean mLoading = false;
private RequestQueue rq;
private ItemsListRequestParameter params;
// add the cache object as a class attribute
private BitmapLruImageCache cache;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, resource, 
            objects);
    mCtx = context;
    items = (ArrayList<Item>) objects;
    rq = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(mCtx);

    // instantiate the cache object on the constructor
    int cacheSize = getCacheSize();
    BitmapLruImageCache cache = new BitmapLruImageCache(cacheSize);

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    LayoutInflater vi = ((Activity) mCtx).getLayoutInflater();

    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_list_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ItemsViewHolder(v);
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter viewholder creado " );

    v.setTag(viewHolder);
    viewHolder = (ItemsViewHolder) v.getTag();

    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter posición: " + position);

    if(viewHolder != null){
        if (items.size() > 0){
            Log.d(TAG, "Adapter tamaño lista: " + getCount());
            Item t = items.get(position);
            Log.d(TAG, "Adapter devolviendo item: " + items.get(position).getItemName());
            String foto = t.getItemPicUrl();
            if (foto == null || foto.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                viewHolder.itemPic.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_default_item_thumbnail);
            }else{

                ImageLoader imgLoader = 
                        new ImageLoader(SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(mCtx),
                                cache);

                viewHolder.itemPic.setImageUrl(foto, imgLoader);
            }
            viewHolder.itemName.setText(t.getItemName());
            viewHolder.itemData1.setText(t.getData1());

        }
    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Adapter viewHolder null: " );
    }
    /**************************************************/
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.getView posición: " + position + "; pageSize: " + pageSize + "; currentPage: " + currentPage);
    if (position +2 == (this.pageSize * (this.currentPage +1)  )&& !mLoading){
        Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.getView pidiendo nuevos datos");
        if(this.params == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "Adapter.getView params null " );
        }else{
            Log.w(TAG, "Adapter.getView nueva carga" );
            this.params.nextPage();
            this.loadData(this.params, pageSize);
        }
    }

    return v;
}


public int getCacheSize() {
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mCtx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    final int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    final int screenBytes = screenWidth * screenHeight * 4; // 4 bytes per pixel

    return screenBytes * 3;
}




@Override
public void add(Item object) {
    items.add(object);
    Log.d(TAG, "Item añadida a adapter: " + object.getItemName());
}
@Override
public void clear() {
    //super.clear();
    items.clear();
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}



static class ItemsViewHolder{
    TextView        itemName;
    TextView        itemData1;
    NetworkImageView itemPic;

    LinearLayout container;

    public ItemsViewHolder(View v){
        this.itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lti_nombre_item);
        this.itemData1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lti_datos_item1);
        this.itemPic = (NetworkImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tli_r_img);
        this.container = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lti_container);
    }

}



public void loadData(ItemsListRequestParameter params, int pageSize){
    mLoading = true;
    ItemListRequest jr = new ItemListRequest(params, this, this);
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.params = params;
    this.rq.add(jr);    
}



@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.onErrorResponse request con error");
    mLoading = false;
    // TODO meter elemento con mensaje error
    Log.i(TAG, "Adapter.onErrorResponse request respondida " + error.getMessage());

}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.onResponse request respondida " + response.toString());
    mLoading = false;
    Response tr = ResponseParser.parseUltimasItemsJSONresponse(response);
    if (tr.getResponseCode().equalsIgnoreCase("000")){
        DaoList tdl = (DaoList) tr.getResponseInfo(); 
        this.currentPage = tdl.getCurrentPage();
        Log.d(TAG, "Adapter.onResponse  currentPage: " + currentPage);
        Iterator<Dao> it = tdl.iterator();
        //tta.clear();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            Item t = (Item) it.next();
            this.add(t);
        }
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

}
```